# How to Bind with Observable collection of UserControl Type Objects

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls, telerik, observablecollection

I am stuck to a data-binding issue in WPF. Following is the scenario.

I have a **Telerik's** `RadTileView` which is bind to an `ObservableCollection` of type `MyItem`.

```
public class MyItem : UserControl
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
```

`ObservableCollection` is being populated like,

```
        private ObservableCollection<MyItem> items_ = null;
        public ObservableCollection<MyItem> TileItems
        {
            get 
            {
                if (items_ == null)
                {
                    items_ = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
                    items_.Add(new MyItem() { Title = "ABC", Content = "Test Content" });
                    items_.Add(new MyItem() { Title = "DEF", Content = "Test Content1" });
                    items_.Add(new MyItem() { Title = "GHI", Content = "Test Content2" });
                }

                return items_;
            }
            set 
            {
                items_= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TileItems");
            }
        }
```

and the `XAML` is

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="headerTemplate">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, Converter={StaticResource debugconv}}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>

<telerik:RadTileView x:Name="WidgetTileView"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding TileItems}" ColumnWidth="Auto"
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource headerTemplate}">
                </telerik:RadTileView>
```

When I run the above code, it shows three empty `RadTileView` but they are empty, as in figure
[image: Empty Tiles]

If I change the `MyItem` as

```
    public class MyItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
```

Then it starts working as expected, as shown
[image: Correct RadTileView]

I am unable to figure out what is the problem with data binding when I inherit `MyItem` from `UserControl`?

**Edit:**
My requirement is to show the Custom UserControl in content area of `RadTileView` and Title text in the header area of `RadTileView`, how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controls will not use the data templates if the items are not data, plain and simple. Do *not* inherit from `UserControl` if the class is supposed to be data (you are also breaking the model-view-separation if you do).

The item is only evaluated as one entity by the `RadTileView` so if the item as a whole is considered displayable the data templates are ignored. If you must do this then move the `UserControl` to a property and use that in the `ContentTemplate` (which just contains a `ContentPresenter` binding the `Content` to that property containing the `UserControl`).

If you want to adhere to the model-view separation you should not inherit from any UI-related class and your `Content` should contain data, this can then be templated in the `ContentTemplate` with the `UserControls` you want.

Comment: Items will actually contain custom `UserControls`, I have just shown an example here. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @Ummar: It's not logically possible, what do you want to display the `UserControl` or the `ItemTemplate` you defined? It cannot be both and in case you have a `UIElement` it will just display that as is and ignore the `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: it will contains browser control or any other control which user can create and load in a new `RadTileView` I hope it clears the question, FYI, I am using PRISM and MEF.

Comment: @Ummar: No, it does not. `UserControl` vs. `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate`, do you still not get it?

Comment: What I want, is to display `UserControl` as Content of `RadTileView` and its `Title` in header of `RadTileView`. I think now it answers your question.

Comment: @Ummar: That was a lot more clear, still the answer is that this cannot work as the item is only evaluated as one entity by the `RadTileView` so if the item as a whole is considered displayable the templates are ignored. As i said you should not have collections containing UIElements anyway because that violates the model-view separation, if you must do this then move the UserControl to a property and use that in the `ContentTemplate` (which just contains a `ContentPresenter` binding the `Content` to that property containing the `UserControl`)

Comment: @Ummar: If you want to adhere to the model-view separation you should not inherit from any UI-related class and your `Content` should contain data, this can then be templated in the `ContentTemplate` with the `UserControls` you want.

Comment: Thanks for all your time and nice suggestions, specially about moving the `UserControl` to a child property, I think that it will work for me, but as a workaround what I have done is edited the `HeaderStyle` of `RadTileView` and in the control template I have added a lable binded to `Title`, and its working. :)

Comment: @Ummar: You tricked the control i see. By the way, the [`Label`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.label.aspx) class serves a specific function, i would recommend reading the remarks section in the documentation and switching to a `ContentPresenter` or `TextBlock`. Also if you want me to move the comments above into my answer i could do that, in any case you should either accept my answer or submit your own and accept that.

Comment: Please move your comments to answer, The content presenter was not working some how, that's why I used Label.

Comment: @Ummar: That is odd, in that case you should try a `ContentControl`, which is a more generic base class of `Label`. Moved comments (you could also suggest edits for any refinements if you want).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this because you are binding UIElements.  So, WPF will use them as its items, not your class properties.